# Why might you want to enable impersonation in ASP.NET IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've read a lot of documentation on how to enable impersonation in an ASP.Net application, but there's no good explanation on why you would want to do this? What are some use cases where you would want to enable this?

PS: Any reason why you might not want to enable this?

Thanks
James